# How to enable Spa middleware in existing MVC application at specific route

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, single-page-application, asp-net-core-spa-services

By default, SPA is enabled on site root. However, I would like to move it to a specific path, e.g: `http://localhost:port/frontend`

```
//public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
{
    configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/dist/myApp";
});

//public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
app.Map("/frontend", frontendApp =>
{
    frontendApp.UseSpaStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
    {
        RequestPath = "/frontend'
    });
    frontendApp.UseSpa(spa =>
    {
        spa.Options.SourcePath = "/ClientApp"; 
        if (Configuration.GetValue<bool>("UseAngularCliServer"))                     
        {
           spa.UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer("http://localhost:4200/");
        }
    });
});
```

This would work when I run npm build in the /frontend folder, but I have trouble configuring UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer. It shows index.html, but refereces

`http://localhost:port/vendor.js` instead of `http://localhost:port/frontend/vendor.js`

and when I use `ng serve --base-href=/vnext/`

the request to localhost:port/frontend/vendor.js returns content of index.html.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm having a similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you should use `frontendApp` parameter instead of `app`:

```
app.Map("/frontend", frontendApp =>
{
    frontendApp.UseSpaStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
    {
        //RequestPath = ??
    });
    frontendApp.UseSpa(spa =>
    {
        //spa.Options.DefaultPageStaticFileOptions.RequestPath = ??;
        spa.Options.SourcePath = "/ClientApp"; 
    });
});
```

Comment: You are right, but this required also `RequestPath = "/frontend"` on UseSpaStaticFiles and also angular probably has to be configured to work on different url than root url

Answer (score 0):

For requesting `http://localhost:port/frontend/vendor.js`, we need to specify **--base-href**, I suggest you try scripts in `package.json` below:

```
"start": "ng serve --base-href=/frontend/ --serve-path=/ --live-reload-client=https://localhost:port/frontend/sockjs-node/",
```

For another option, you could try code below in `Startup`

```
        app.Map("/frontend", frontendApp =>
        {
            frontendApp.UseSpa(spa =>
            {
                // To learn more about options for serving an Angular SPA from ASP.NET Core,
                // see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=864501

                spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

                if (env.IsDevelopment())
                {
                    spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start --  --base-href=/frontend/ --serve-path=/ --live-reload-client=https://localhost:44302/frontend/sockjs-node/");
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: what does `--serve-path=/` do in this context? Why do I need to repeat the attributes in UseAngularCliServer()? I thought it will invoke `npm start` which already contains the attributes. Also --base-href will affect HttpClient's calls to  APIs, won't it? so instaed of `/Api/SomeApiController` it will go to `/frontend/Api/SomeController`

Comment: `Package.json` and `spa.UseAngularCliServer`, use one of them. There is no need to combine them together.

Comment: oh, ok. what about the --serve-path?

Comment: There is no much information about this, and it seems this is not required. You may consider go to npm site for help.